# Перекрещивание процессов на Python сервере

Tags: python, flask

Есть сервис на Flask, при выполнении скрипта плюс-минус одновременно из нескольких окон браузера получается так, что данные запущенные из разных окон при выполнении начинают перекрещиваться и в конечном итоге сливаются, сохраняясь в одну и ту же переменную скрипта (чего хотелось бы избежать и сделать так чтобы каждый процесс из отдельного окна браузера  был отделен от другого, функция везде задействуется одна и та же, так что при ее одновременном выполнении получается, что она сохраняет данные в одну и ту же переменную только в разных процессах). Хотелось бы сделать так чтобы при выполнении программы из разных окон браузера данные получаемые в ходе выполнения скрипта были четко дифференцированы друг от друга и не сливались в конечном итоге.
Надеюсь понятно объяснил свою мысль. Возможно что то в скрипте нужно дополнить, а возможно как то настроить, не знаю...

Comment: Есть множество толкований вопроса и разные варианты проблем. Нужно привести хотя бы схематично, как выглядит обработка. Главный вопрос: вы используете глобальные переменные для хранения данных между запросами от одного клиента? Если так, то это корень ваших проблем. Два запроса от одного клиента могут обрабатываться разными процессами на сервере, и значит обработчик второго запроса от того же клиента увидит не свои данные.

Comment: @Roman Konoval
Да, использую, думаю в этом и состоит проблема, большое спасибо, попробую поправить =)